# how to edit the ~/.gvimrc.after and make modifications correctly?

Tags: vi, vim

I was looking to install a new theme to vim. So I found one that I liked and was following along to the tutorial at http://astonj.com/tech/vim-for-ruby-rails-and-a-sexy-theme/

it first had me install Janus. Then I downloaded the CodeSchool theme and I was supposed to just put it in the `.vim/colors`. So I looked in there but noticed that all the other theme were laid out differently, there were not just `.vim` files, but `theme_name/colors/theme_name.vim` [image: How the colors are laid out]

So I created a similar layout. But then I was supposed to open `~/.gvimrc.after` and paste in

```
color codeschool
set guifont=Monaco:h12
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"
set guioptions-=T " Removes top toolbar
set guioptions-=r " Removes right hand scroll bar
set go-=L " Removes left hand scroll bar
autocmd User Rails let b:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "<% \r %>" " displays <% %> correctly
:set cpoptions+=$ " puts a $ marker for the end of words/lines in cw/c$ commands
```

I only found a `.gvimrc`

[image: Actual directory organization]

It contained

```
if filereadable(expand("~/.gvimrc.before"))
  source ~/.gvimrc.before
endif

" CtrlP OS-X Menu remapping
if janus#is_plugin_enabled('ctrlp') && has("gui_macvim")
  macmenu &File.New\ Tab key=<D-S-t>
endif

if filereadable(expand("~/.gvimrc.after"))
  source ~/.gvimrc.after
endif
```

So not really sure if this might be the file of the next step from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are following the instructions.

`~/.gvimrc.before` is in your home directory. (Notice the `~`? its the standard symbol for your home directory)

To edit it just type `:e ~/.gvimrc.before` from inside gvim.

---

To install just the colorscheme the only things necessary are to put it in the folder `~/.vim/colors/<colorscheme_name>.vim`

And have the following in your vimrc (or gvimrc)

```
colorscheme <colorscheme_name>
```

---

Recommendation. Get rid of Janus. Install and configure everything for vim by hand. Debugging someone else's configuration will be very hard down the road. And you have no idea what you actually installed or how to use it.

Comment: I followed what you said as best as I could. I had a challenge with `:e ~/.gvimrc.before` as I got an error that said `-bash: :e command not found` so I modified the `.vimrc` and put in `colorscheme codeschool`. Seems fine but now watching the tutorials to see where to go from here, thanks.

Comment: `:e ~/.gvimrc.before` was supposed to happen in vim. If you want to edit when you are outside of vim do `vim ~/.gvimrc.before`

Answer (score 4):

The symptom:

You can't follow the simple installation instructions for a colorscheme.

The cause:

You have installed Janus. That thing is an horrible piece of crap that adds a dozen of unecessary layers of weird abstractions to something that's otherwise incredibly easy.

The solution:

Remove that absurdly messy Janus crap as soon as possible and do things normally with a normal `~/.vimrc` file for your settings and a normal `~/.vim/` directory for your plugins and colorschemes.

Colorschemes are simple `filename.vim` files that go into `~/.vim/colors/`. In your case,

```
~/.vim/colors/codeschool.vim
```

Simple, Clean. Perfect.

Comment: Thanks, I added the theme to `.vim/colors/` and then typed in `colorscheme codeschool` . this time no error, so seemed fine. I began working on a file but did not see it look like the demo. I did create a .vimrc and pasted in the content per the tutorial but got the error `.vimrc" E166: Can't open linked file for writing` I searched the error and now saying to delete and redo?

Comment: @JGallardo are you using (command line) vim or gvim (or MacVim)? (If you are using vim that might be why the colors look different). And is the `.vimrc` file a symlink or hardlink (Thats what the error seems to suggest)

Comment: @FDinoff oh that explains it, I was in the command line. But when I opened up MacVim, I saw the appropriate syntax highlighting there. Not sure how it is linked, but not seeing the error anymore.